# Need to simplify javascript function (also using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a bit of a long function for uploading photos using hidden iFrames, it works great and everything, the thing is it's a lot of messy code, and I would like to make a clean function that only has a few rows or such for making it easier and less code to work with.

```
function fileUpload(form, action_url)
{
// Create the iframe...
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("id","upload_iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("name","upload_iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("width","0");
iframe.setAttribute("height","0");
iframe.setAttribute("border","0");
iframe.setAttribute("style","width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");

// Add to document...
form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
window.frames['upload_iframe'].name="upload_iframe";

iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

// Add event...
var eventHandler = function()  {

if (iframeId.detachEvent)
iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
else
iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);

// Message from server...
if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
} else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
} else if (iframeId.document) {
content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
}
if(content)
{
/* THIS CODE SHOULD BE DEFINED IN NEW FUNCTION, AND PLACED HER AUTOMATICALLY- onSuccess()
$('img.profile-picture').attr("src","photos/"+content+"_200.jpg");
$('.post-photo'+cookie('login')).attr("src","photos/"+content+"_55.jpg");
$(".add-photo-loading").fadeOut("fast");
*/
}
else
{
/*THIS SHOULD ALSO BE DEFINED IN THE NEW FUNCTION - onError()
$(".add-photo-loading").html("Invalid Filetype");
$(".add-photo-loading").attr("class","upload-error");
*/
}
// Del the iframe...
setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
}

if (iframeId.addEventListener)
iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
if (iframeId.attachEvent)
iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

// Set properties of form...
form.setAttribute("target","upload_iframe");
form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
form.setAttribute("method","post");
form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");

// Submit the form...
form.submit();
/*THIS SHOULD BE FIRED IMMEDIATELY WHEN THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED BUT THIS CODE SHOULD ALSO BE FIRED ELSEWHERE 
$(".upload-error").attr("class","add-photo-loading");
$(".add-photo-loading").html("Uploading...");
$(".add-photo-loading").css({"display":"block"});
*/
}
```

Okay, so there are a few lines of code in here that should be defined in the new function and I have /**/ commented around the blocks of code, with the action that is for that block.

Comment: I'd remove extra commented code. Then I'd move iframe/form parameters to an associative array and set the iframe/form parameters by looping through that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function fileUpload(a, b) {
var c = document.createElement("iframe");
c.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe"), c.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe"), c.setAttribute("width", "0"), c.setAttribute("height", "0"), c.setAttribute("border", "0"), c.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;"), a.parentNode.appendChild(c), window.frames.upload_iframe.name = "upload_iframe", iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");
var d = function () {
    iframeId.detachEvent ? iframeId.detachEvent("onload", d) : iframeId.removeEventListener("load", d, !1), iframeId.contentDocument ? content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML : iframeId.contentWindow ? content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML : iframeId.document && (content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML), setTimeout("iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)", 250)
};
iframeId.addEventListener && iframeId.addEventListener("load", d, !0), iframeId.attachEvent && iframeId.attachEvent("onload", d), a.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe"), a.setAttribute("action", b), a.setAttribute("method", "post"), a.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data"), a.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data"), a.submit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to make a base class with all the common functionality in it and then make a new a class which extends from it which has more specific functionality in it.

e.g. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: Thanks, looks a bit confusing as a never using this before.

Comment: A bit off topic but have you tried using coffescript instead of plain JS? It is a bit neater (and compiles to JS anyway). It makes things a bit clearer and easier to understand/read.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe method it's "deprecated" int 2.0 Web age.

Please, forgot innerHTML and other not standard ways.

If you are planning to use Jquery, the task could me simpler and efficient.

Here you can see it seeing this demo
[Jquery Upload File Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

And here you get the reference and how-tos
[Jquery Upload Documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

Comment: I don’t think `<iframe>` is deprecated — it’s sitting there quite happily in the HTML5 spec (see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-iframe-element.html#the-iframe-element) — and jQuery itself appears to use `innerHTML` 16 times (see http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js).

Comment: Thank you for providing links. It would be even better if you provided example code. Don't make the reader chase those links, give them an answer right here.

Comment: innerHTML is not "non-standard" - it is actually the defined method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML

There are also plenty of occasions where using an iframe is perfectly logical, such as the XHR upload of files

Comment: many, or most jQuery plugins have iFrames for a fallback method anyways.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite iframe, also it's potentially a security riks. Just research some. Jquery uses innerHTML because it's cross platform. Futhermore, innerHTML it's a IE "propietary" property. And not standard.

Comment: And I told "deprecated", not deprecated. xD

Comment: What’s the iframe security risk in this context?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Here you are http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/10/24/iframes-security-summary/

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt Read & study documentation, wikis, etc it's a MUST. I can't provide more help because perhaps I use Jquery frequently, those plugin it's unknow for me. But I think can't be hard to use. The secret it's in docs and examples.

Comment: As per that page, “The use of iframes on your web site is not a security risk as long as you are not referencing external sites.” As far as I can tell, the OP isn’t referencing an external site with his iframe.